# $A$ is an invertible Matrix of order $m$. Then there will exist an upper triangular matrix $B$ such that $AB$ is an Orthogonal Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$A$ is an invertible Matrix of order $m$. Then there will exist an upper triangular matrix $B$ such that $AB$ is an Orthogonal Matrix.

Can anyone please help me to prove or disprove it by giving some hints?

Comment: Are you familiar with the $QR$ decomposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any real matrix $A$ admits a [QR Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition), where we may write
$$A = Q R$$
where $Q$ is orthogonal and $R$ is upper-triangular. This factorization is traditionally obtained via the Gram-Schmidt Process.

For your question, note that $A$ is invertible, and hence in any factorization of $A$ as a product of two matrices $Q$ and $R$ will have to have both $Q$ and $R$ invertible. So if we choose $B$ to be $R^{-1}$ (recall that the inverse of an upper-triangular matrix is upper-triangular), where $R$ is obtained from the QR decomposition, then $AB = A R^{-1} = (QR) R^{-1} = Q$ will be orthogonal.